# How do I find the example of a continuous surjective function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ such that inverse image of dense set is not dense?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

How do I find the example of a continuous surjective function $f: X \rightarrow Y$ such that inverse image of dense set is not dense?

Can anyone suggest some hints for this question?

Comment: Try to find a proof that the inverse image of a dense subset under a continuous function is dense.  See why such a proof might fail.  This should help you find a counterexample.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: what if $X$ has the discrete topology?

Answer (score 0):

What about

$$\begin{array}{l|rcl}
f : & X= \mathbb R & \longrightarrow & Y = [0,\infty) \\
    & x & \longmapsto & \begin{cases}0 & x <0\\ x & x \ge 0\end{cases}\end{array}$$

$(0,\infty)$ is dense in $Y$ but $f^{-1}[(0,\infty)] = (0,\infty)$ is not dense in $\mathbb R$.